# Share data layer for outsourcing project

Tags: project-management, asp.net, outsourcing

We are a small team of programmers, and we are now facing a situation where we have to outsource some of the work in order to complete it in time.

Project is about website that was previously build with asp.net webforms, EF and SQL server. We have previously build a data layer and optimized SQL, but we need to complete front end of the project. Clients wants asp.net MVC and HTML5.

The problem for us is how to open data layer to outsourcing team without compromising or disclosing any data?

Comment: Why do you assume data is going to be compromised? Which data would be?

Comment: A database user with limited access, an interface over the database exposing only the data necessary, database with mock data. There are many options. The choice would depend on what you already have.

Comment: *"we have to outsource some of the work in order to complete it in time"* - do you know about [Brooks's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks's_law)? It is not on topic of your question, but I have a strong negative experience of outsourcing in such situations.

Comment: @superM you gave me a good idea, what if data layer would return only a single row for fragile data (test user info, test credit card info etc)

Comment: @scriptin what would happen if a company signed us to do the front end. wouldn't they end up in the same situation as we are now?

Comment: From my experience, such data is either replaced with mock data, or even better the company creates an account (if credit card will actually be used) for testing purposes.

Comment: @John If they're in a hurry and they hire you as additional manpower - yes, it's a case of Brooks's law. The point is: adding manpower to a project slows down the process (during the "ramp up" period, which may span past the deadline). Of course, if you just can't do some part of the job (e.g. your team has no frontend developer), then there is no other choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem for us is how to open data layer to outsourcing team without compromising or disclosing any data

- then just don't give them access to the data. You will have to provide non-critical test data instead.
- if you cannot do this for some kind of reason, let the outsourcing team sign a non-disclosure agreement
- if you suspect the outsourcing team to misuse the data either, you should seriously consider not to hire them.